# How can I decode text?

Tags: c#, json, decode

Hi guys I have a json response from server with such text:

```
<div class=\"profile-info\">\u0413\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434: \u041a\u043e\u0432\u0440\u043e\u0432<\/div>
```

How to decode `\u0413\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434: \u041a\u043e\u0432\u0440\u043e\u0432`?

Comment: Typically users on SO that post questions indicate what they've tried before.  When they don't, they often receive downvotes.  What have you tried?

Comment: It's actually not very trivial. The exact rules can be found in http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/ . Iirc the chapter about parsing or tokenization.

Comment: Does the text actually contain the character sequence `\u0413` and so on, or are you looking at the text with the Visual Studio Debugger (which shows strings as C# literal)?

Comment: And you're parsing the JSON response with a JSON parser, right? JSON  (like C#) uses escape sequences in strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\\u([a-f0-9]{4})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
String result = regex.Replace(result, match => ((Char)Int32.Parse(match.Value.Substring(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToString());
```

Comment: He asked how to decode that sequence of unicode character escapes... so here is the answer.